# Bad SQLite performance on external storage in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, database-performance

I'm using the external storage for storing events in a database while they are waiting to be sent to the server.

I'm seeing really bad performance when inserting records.
I know the external memory can be slow but I wanted to see some number so I wrote a small app which tests it.

Here is the code:

```
public static final int INSERTS = 100;

File dbFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test.sqlite3");
// File dbFile = new File(getFilesDir(), "test.sqlite3");
dbFile.delete();

SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(dbFile, null);

db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE events (_id integer primary key autoincrement, event_type TEXT NOT NULL, timestamp BIGINT, data TEXT);");
db.execSQL("CREATE INDEX mainIndex ON events (event_type, timestamp ASC);");

InsertHelper helper = new InsertHelper(db, "events");

final int eventTypeCol = helper.getColumnIndex("event_type");
final int timestampCol = helper.getColumnIndex("timestamp");
final int dataCol = helper.getColumnIndex("data");

long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

String eventType = "foo", data = "bar";
long timestamp = 4711;

for(int i = 0; i < INSERTS; ++i) {
    helper.prepareForInsert();
    helper.bind(eventTypeCol, eventType);
    helper.bind(timestampCol, timestamp);
    helper.bind(dataCol, data);
    helper.execute();
}

long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

Log.i("Test", String.format("InsertHelper, Speed: %d ms, Records per second: %.2f", (int)(end-start), 1000*(double)INSERTS/(double)(end-start)));

db.close();
dbFile.delete();

db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(dbFile, null);

db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE events (_id integer primary key autoincrement, event_type TEXT NOT NULL, timestamp BIGINT, data TEXT);");
db.execSQL("CREATE INDEX mainIndex ON events (event_type, timestamp ASC);");


start = System.currentTimeMillis();
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

for(int i = 0; i < INSERTS; ++i) {
    cv.put("event_type", eventType);
    cv.put("timestamp", timestamp);
    cv.put("data", data);
    db.insert("events", null, cv);
}

end = System.currentTimeMillis();

Log.i("Test", String.format("Normal, Speed: %d ms, Records per second: %.2f", end-start, 1000*(double)INSERTS/(double)(end-start)));

db.close();
dbFile.delete();
```

The database is exactly as the one my real app is using, I tried removing the index but it made no difference.

Here are the results:

```
Nexus One, Internal memory

      Method | Records | Time (ms) | Records per second
-------------+---------+-----------+--------------------
      Normal |   100   |    2072   |       48.26
InsertHelper |   100   |    1662   |       60.17


Nexus One, External memory:

      Method | Records | Time (ms) | Records per second
-------------+---------+-----------+--------------------
      Normal |   100   |    7390   |       13.53
InsertHelper |   100   |    7152   |       13.98


Emulator, Internal memory:

      Method | Records | Time (ms) | Records per second
-------------+---------+-----------+--------------------
      Normal |   100   |    1803   |       55.46
InsertHelper |   100   |    3075   |       32.52


Emulator, External memory:

      Method | Records | Time (ms) | Records per second
-------------+---------+-----------+--------------------
      Normal |   100   |    5742   |       17.42
InsertHelper |   100   |    7164   |       13.96
```

As you can see the emulator cannot be trusted, [`InsertHelper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.InsertHelper.html) should be faster if anything.
This is, of course, to be expected, the test was mostly done out of curiosity.

What have me concerned however is the bad performance on my phone when using external memory, have I missed some crucial aspect of [`SQLiteDatabase`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) or is it simply so that the SD card will be slow?

I can add that in my real app I've disabled [locking](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#setLockingEnabled(boolean)) and it makes little difference.

Comment: Unless you have a really good reason to put your database on external storage, I wouldn't do that. External storage on Android 1.x and 2.x is not always available (e.g., user mounts the storage as a drive on their desktop or notebook). Also, for measuring I/O bound operations, the emulator will bear little resemblance to production hardware, because the emulator is not using flash for anything (internal or external), but rather is using disk image files on your development machine.

Comment: The problem is the database might grow, it will probably have a max limit of about 10MB or so, I don't want to take up so much space internally.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

CommonsWare is correct in his comment. Something that makes a big difference for db performance is using transactions. Wrap your insert loop in a transaction. I'm not 100% sure if it would work with the InsertHelper but you can try replacing your for loop with this:

```
db.beginTransaction();
try {
    for(int i = 0; i < INSERTS; ++i) {
        helper.prepareForInsert();
        helper.bind(eventTypeCol, eventType);
        helper.bind(timestampCol, timestamp);
        helper.bind(dataCol, data);
        helper.execute();
    }
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

Comment: Transactions gave me 925 records per second, amazing :)

Comment: Actually, `InsertHelper.execute()` uses return values instead of exceptions so you should check if it returns -1 instead.

Answer (score 2):

I have some db performance issues so I used your code to measure the inserts per second on my system. But I also added wrapping in {begin,end}Transaction().

In the emulator. I got:

```
InsertHelper-Internal-Trans, Speed: 67 ms, Records per second: 1492.54
InsertHelper-External-Trans, Speed: 70 ms, Records per second: 1428.57
Normal-Internal-Trans, Speed: 148 ms, Records per second: 675.68
Normal-External-Trans, Speed: 152 ms, Records per second: 657.89
InsertHelper-Internal-NoTrans, Speed: 514 ms, Records per second: 194.55
Normal-Internal-NoTrans, Speed: 519 ms, Records per second: 192.68
InsertHelper-External-NoTrans, Speed: 590 ms, Records per second: 169.49
Normal-External-NoTrans, Speed: 618 ms, Records per second: 161.81
```

And on a Samsung Galaxy Note:

```
InsertHelper-External-Trans, Speed: 52 ms, Records per second: 1923.08
InsertHelper-Internal-Trans, Speed: 52 ms, Records per second: 1923.08
Normal-External-Trans, Speed: 77 ms, Records per second: 1298.70
Normal-Internal-Trans, Speed: 121 ms, Records per second: 826.45
Normal-External-NoTrans, Speed: 4562 ms, Records per second: 21.92
Normal-Internal-NoTrans, Speed: 4855 ms, Records per second: 20.60
InsertHelper-External-NoTrans, Speed: 5997 ms, Records per second: 16.68
InsertHelper-Internal-NoTrans, Speed: 8361 ms, Records per second: 11.96
```